# Present tense or past tense when using get/ got

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage

Do you and James  get sunburned on the balcony?
Yes, we get sunburned on the balcony.

I read the question and answer and they seem incorrect to me.

Should they be :
Did you and James get sunburned on the balcony?
Yes, we got sunburned on the balcony.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily. Using the past tense here would indicate a single occurrence, but the present tense is correct if there have been multiple occurrences and more are possible  - like if they often (or even occasionally) go out to the balcony, which can get them sunburned.